# Androidの自作プラグインでjarライブラリーを使いたい。

Tags: monaca, cordova

monacaを使ってAndroidアプリを開発しています。
Androidの自作プラグインでメーカー提供のjarライブラリーを使いたいのですが
jarライブラリーの格納先、及びclasspathの設定がわかりません。

cordovaだと/platforms/android/libsのフォルダーにjarライブラリーを格納することで
自作プラグインのビルドが完了できるのですがmonacaではこのようなフォルダーが見当たりません。

monacaでjarライブラリーを取り扱う場合はどうすればいいのかを教えて頂けないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

プラグインを作成するのであれば、plugman形式にする必要があります。
plugman形式であれば、jarファイルもjavaファイルと同様に組み込むことが出来ます。
例えば、
https://github.com/NIFTYCloud-mbaas/monaca_push_plugin
を参考にしてみてください。

このプラグインでは、NCMB.jarというjarファイルを扱っています。plugin.xml内で

```
<lib-file src="src/android/libs/NCMB.jar" />
```

と記述してありますが、この記述があると、このプラグインを組み込んだ場合、プロジェクトの
libディレクトリに自動的にNCMB.jarが設定されます。(Cordova/Monacaで共通の仕様です）